# How can I fill the empty space behind a bug screen installed on these stone arches?

Tags: outdoor, mortar, stone, screens

I want to install bug screens in the open stone arches of my sunroom. I have flexible screen retainers ready to replace the wood that the previous owner roughly installed for the same purpose.

[image]

The problem I’m trying to solve is with the deep spaces between the stones that I’d be screwing into. I’d at best have 3 inches of open air behind the screen retainers (in the mortar joints) if I just screwed them into the stone face and left it alone. You can see a similar problem here with the wood currently installed. Hello bugs.

[image]

What is the best way to build up a backing or otherwise bug seal up those gaps? Is it just to use type N mortar and create a smooth surface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea - you're either looking at a VERY tedious scribing job for a filler board, or a relatively very simple "pack it with masonry" approach, unless there's some suitable surface outside where you could just run the screen to cover both the opening and the stonework, but you might not like that look.

Might use less-robust mortar (type O) to simplify removal if ever desired. This is a very non-structural application where its low strength won't have a downside.

Comment: Or, of course, the messy and highly regrettable "modern" approach of spray-foaming it...which I do not recommend, in spades.

Comment: There's a lot of polymer foams which would conform to the masonry shape, or be easily cuttable to size, but I don't know what is suitably weather, UV and pest resistant for this purpose. You'd certainly want a closed cell one...